# PHP regex: Detect language string from beginning of url

Tags: php, regex

I try to detect and then remove language string from list of urls:

```
$url_samples = [
'en/buy-a-ticket', // ok
'en/tickets/something', // ok
'en', // problem
'en/', // ok
'enhu', // ok
'en-hu/niecohu', // ok
'sk/hu-ngary', // ok
'hu/contact', // ok
];
```

Everything [goes well](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/AUO) with my regex `/^([en|hu]{2})\/.*|^([en|hu]{2})$/` with `$matched` array like:

```
array (
 0 => en/reservation/index
 1 => en
)
```

All expect url `en` (url of foreign language frontpage `https://www.example.com/en`). It is matched but `$matched` array looks like:

```
array ( 
 0 => en
 1 =>  
 2 => en
)
```

I want array with 2 results, not 3. *Can you help?*

NOTE: I can add additional conditions to `detectLanguage()`  but I want to go 'regex improvent' way.

I attach final function for complete image of use:

```
/**
 * Goals: Detect language, clean url
 */
function detectLanguage( $url ) {

    if (preg_match( '/^([en|hu]{2})\/.*|^([en|hu]{2})$/', $url, $match )) {

        $result[ 'detected_language' ] = $match[ 1 ];
        $result[ 'cleaned_url' ] = preg_replace( '/^' . $match[ 1 ] . '\//', '', $url );
    } else {

        $result[ 'detected_language' ] = null;
        $result[ 'cleaned_url' ] = $url;
    }

    return $result;

}

print_r( detectLanguage( $url_samples[ 0 ] ) );
print_r( detectLanguage( $url_samples[ 1 ] ) );
print_r( detectLanguage( $url_samples[ 2 ] ) );
print_r( detectLanguage( $url_samples[ 3 ] ) );
```

Comment: Is your problem related to absolute vs relative URLs?

Comment: Hi, my problem is related to relative url. Value I get from $url = preg_replace( '{^/|\?.*}', '', $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] ); It cleans url of the query and leading slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `([en|ru]{2})` does do what you think it does. It is a character class matching that repeats 2 times matching one chars of `e` `n` `|` `r` `u`

To prevent getting the empty entry, you could shorten your pattern to a single capturing group preventing without the alternation `|` and make matching the `/` and the rest of the line after it optional.

```
^(en|ru)(?:/.*)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(en|ru)` Capture group 1, match either `en` or `ru`
- `(?:/.*)?` Optionally match `/` and the rest of the string
- `$` End of string

See s [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j4KJ7L/1) and a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/JNHBt).

```
$strings = [
    "en/buy-a-ticket",
    "en/tickets/something",
    "en",
    "en/",
    "enhu",
    "en-hu/niecohu",
    "sk/hu-ngary",
    "hu/contact"
];

$regex = "~^(en|ru)(?:/.*)?$~";
foreach ($strings as $s) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $s, $match)) {
        print_r($match);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => en/buy-a-ticket
    [1] => en
)
Array
(
    [0] => en/tickets/something
    [1] => en
)
Array
(
    [0] => en
    [1] => en
)
Array
(
    [0] => en/
    [1] => en
)
```

Comment: That's it, thank you. I found bug in `preg_replace` but that's for another question.